# Django formset data does not get saved when initial values are provided

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have a formset which has some initial data provided - it's a data cloned from other model which contains 2 fields 'group' and 'requested'.

When initial data is provided the forms in formset do not get saved, they only get saved when I'll modify the form with the data a little bit.

When no initial data is provided forms do get saved.

Why adding intial data to a formset makes it impossible to save formsets data to the database?

This is my formset existing in get_context_data dictionary:

```
        initial = ProcedureActionGroup.objects.filter(procedure__id=self.kwargs.get('pk', None))
        initial_values = initial.values('group', 'requested')
        print initial_values
        initial_count = initial.count()

        ActionGroupFormset = inlineformset_factory(self.model, TaskGroup, extra=initial_count,
                                                   form=TaskActionGroupForm,
                                                   can_delete=False,
                                                   )
        data['formset'] = ActionGroupFormset(self.request.POST or None, initial=initial_values,
                                             **self.get_formset_kwargs())
```

This is my form_valid method where I save all data

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    forms = []
    forms.append(form.is_valid())
    if self.get_procedure_obj():
        formset = context['formset']
        forms.append(formset.is_valid())

    if all(forms):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        form.save()
        if self.get_procedure_obj():
            formset = formset.save(commit=False)
            for obj in formset:
                obj.task = self.object
                obj.save()

        self.object.extract_users()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())
```

Model:

```
class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, null=True, blank=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(ActionGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    requested = models.PositiveIntegerField(u'Requested', null=True, blank=True)
```

form template:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="span6 offset2 form form-horizontal">
    {% crispy form%}
    {{formset.management_form}}
    {% if formset %}
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                {% for form in formset%}
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form %}
                     <td> {{field}} </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is your question, "Why can I only save the data in a form after I've add some values"? Also are you using the `placeholder` attribute to supply the initial data in the form?

Comment: Yes. I don't use placeholders.

Comment: Why would you want to save the info without any interaction? Also can you post the model that `obj` represents?

Comment: I have some predefined data which needs to get saved. I eventually might need to change 1 value (requested).

Comment: I'm still groping for whats going on. How is the form saved? a submit button onclick? Could you post that as well

Comment: On button click - single form gets saved, but formset does not when it has initial unmodified data. I've added the form

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional info. I think this might be an HTML problem and not a Django one. Your Django code seems to be in working order, its just that the form only gets initialized when you click it. I suggest posting a different question with "why can I only get this values from a form when I click submit" as the focus. You can link it to this one as well. My hunch is that until the form is click Django is unable to access it until it is interacted with for some reason. Either way this might be a common HTML form problem.

Comment: I've discovered that it might be something else. Initial data is being treaded as already existing objects. When I iterate over formset each form returns False for form.has_changed(). So it means that I need to force each form to "change".

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. Answer your  own question in case anyone else runs into it!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue using django extra views.

I solved it bay modifying the form class that is passed to the inlineformset_factory.  the ModelForm.has_changed method was returning false.

```
class TaskActionGroupForm(ModelForm):

    model = YourModel

    def has_changed(self):
        """
        Overriding this, as the initial data passed to the form does not get noticed, 
        and so does not get saved, unless it actually changes
        """
        changed_data = super(ModelForm, self).has_changed()
        return bool(self.initial or changed_data)
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times, just saved my ass at work :D

Answer (score 1):

In exmaple above I used inlineformset_factory which treaded values passed to initial as already existing objects.

So when I looped over my formset with:

```
for form in formset:
   form.has_changed()
```

form.has_changed() returned False

I've repleaced inlineformset_factory to formset_factory which treats intial data as new data which get's saved correctly. Code example will be posted tomorrow.

Comment: any news? has been a long time since tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; Remove `initial` on `POST`.**

I have myself faced this issue in Django admin with the formsets generated by using `InlineModelAdmin`. What I was trying to achieve was to prefill the inline forms using `get_formset_kwars` to reduce the need for data entry by the user.

However, it took me a while to discover why the prefilled data was never saved. It seemed random and buggy, but after a lot of Googling, I did find out that `initial` data is never saved if it has not changed. This is a *feature not a bug* although a confusing one.

Long story short, the simplest method for me was to remove the `initial` property when the `request.method` is `POST`. That way, Django cannot establish that the initial data has not changed, and will save the related models as intended.